# "where" clause: entity id is in a potentially null array

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an array of office ids, and the array is potentially null.  I want the EF query to return *all* records if the officeIdsToSelect array is null, or only the matching records if it is not null.
However this:

```
int[] officeIdsToSelect = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Office[] selectedOffices = (from item in new TdsDb().Offices
                            where (officeIdsToSelect == null || officeIdsToSelect.Contains(item.OfficeID))
                            select item).ToArray();
```

throws an exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.
```

Specifically Linq to Entities is objecting to `officeIdsToSelect == null`.  I understand what it's saying (one of the clearer EF error messages...)

So how can I get what I want here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF can't translate `officeIdsToSelect == null` to SQL.

In the other hand, EF is clever enough to translate `officeIdsToSelect.Contains(item.OfficeID)` to `WHERE OfficeID IN (1, 2, 3)`.

So basically, you could simply do:

```
Office[] selectedOffices;
if (officeIdsToSelect == null)
{
    selectedOffices = new TdsDb().Offices.ToArray();
}
else
{
    selectedOffices = (from item in new TdsDb().Offices
                            where officeIdsToSelect.Contains(item.OfficeID)
                            select item).ToArray();
}
```

---

EDIT:

If your actual query is more complicated and you don't want to duplicate it, what you could do is conditionally add a `Where` clause depending on the value of your `int` array.

```
// Here's a query that is NOT YET executed (deferred execution)
var query = (from item in new TdsDb().Offices
                            ...... your whole complicated request here
                            select item);

// Conditionnally adds a where clause if required
if (officeIdsToSelect != null)
{
    // Still not yet executing the query. We're just building the query for now
    query = query.Where(z => officeIdsToSelect.Contains(z.OfficeID));
}

// OK, now executes the query and get the results
Office[] selectedOffices = query.ToArray();
```

---

> if the conditional Where doesn't overwrite the original Where clause;
>   but is addative

Yes, that's the power of LINQ to Entities: **fluent programming** and **deferred execution**.

Fluent programming means you can *chain* methods, and this is possible with LINQ thanks to the `IQueryable` extension methods.

For example, [`IQueryable<T>.Where(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) returns also an `IQueryable<T>` object. It internally adds a *predicate* to the query, then returns the query you specified as parameter.

The other important part is the *deferred execution*. This allow to **not** execute the query until the data is actually requested. It's only when you actually need the data that the request in actually executed against your database.
In the above example, it's the `.ToArray()` command that actually executes the query.

See [this nice MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx) for details about query execution mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The where clause is a compressed version of a much large one, hence why I didn't want to create two complex but essentially duplicated queries.

Comment: That would certainly be a really cool solve to the issue - if the conditional Where doesn't overwrite the original Where clause; but is addative.  Does query = query.Where(z => officeIdsToSelect.Contains(z.OfficeID));  really only add to the existing where logic, as opposed to overwriting it?  Would be really interested in documentation for this.

Comment: I tested myself - and as you say, that works.  Would still like to see the documentation that describes this "addative" behaviour.  Intuitively I'd assume overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
int[] officeIdsToSelect = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var selectedOfficeCount = officeIdsToSelect.Count;
Office[] selectedOffices = (from item in new TdsDb().Offices
                                where (selectedOfficeCount == 0 || officeIdsToSelect.Contains(item.OfficeID))
                                select item).ToArray();
```